# Can I know address from dis assembling

Tags: c, gcc, disassembly

I use gcc. I want to know the address of each and every line of code.Is there any way obtaining it through dis assembling? the first column of dis assembled output seems like address to me, but I am not sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20],address[500];
    printf("enter your name::: \n");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    printf("name you entered is:: %s \n", name);
    printf("enter your name::: \n");
    fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);
    printf("address you entered is:: %s \n", address);
}
```

for above example I want to know address at each and every line.

Comment: You want to use `objdump -S -d <executable or library>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the dissasembly output either by using `gdb` like this (your `main()` function in my gdb):

```
(gdb) disas /m main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
5   {
   0x000000000040066d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040066e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400671 <+4>: sub    $0x220,%rsp
   0x0000000000400678 <+11>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000400681 <+20>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400685 <+24>:    xor    %eax,%eax

6       char name[20],address[500];
7       printf("enter your name::: \n");
   0x0000000000400687 <+26>:    mov    $0x4007a4,%edi
   0x000000000040068c <+31>:    callq  0x400520 <puts@plt>

8       fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
   0x0000000000400691 <+36>:    mov    0x2009c0(%rip),%rdx        # 0x601058 <stdin@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x0000000000400698 <+43>:    lea    -0x220(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040069f <+50>:    mov    $0x14,%esi
   0x00000000004006a4 <+55>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004006a7 <+58>:    callq  0x400560 <fgets@plt>

9       printf("name you entered is:: %s \n", name);
   0x00000000004006ac <+63>:    lea    -0x220(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004006b3 <+70>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x00000000004006b6 <+73>:    mov    $0x4007b8,%edi
   0x00000000004006bb <+78>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004006c0 <+83>:    callq  0x400540 <printf@plt>

10      printf("enter your name::: \n");
   0x00000000004006c5 <+88>:    mov    $0x4007a4,%edi
   0x00000000004006ca <+93>:    callq  0x400520 <puts@plt>

11      fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);
   0x00000000004006cf <+98>:    mov    0x200982(%rip),%rdx        # 0x601058 <stdin@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
   0x00000000004006d6 <+105>:   lea    -0x200(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004006dd <+112>:   mov    $0x1f4,%esi
   0x00000000004006e2 <+117>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004006e5 <+120>:   callq  0x400560 <fgets@plt>

12      printf("address you entered is:: %s \n", address);
   0x00000000004006ea <+125>:   lea    -0x200(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004006f1 <+132>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x00000000004006f4 <+135>:   mov    $0x4007d3,%edi
   0x00000000004006f9 <+140>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004006fe <+145>:   callq  0x400540 <printf@plt>

13  }
   0x0000000000400703 <+150>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
   0x0000000000400707 <+154>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
   0x0000000000400710 <+163>:   je     0x400717 <main+170>
   0x0000000000400712 <+165>:   callq  0x400530 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x0000000000400717 <+170>:   leaveq 
   0x0000000000400718 <+171>:   retq   

End of assembler dump.
```

or by using some disassembling utility like `objdump` (`test` is my executable file resulted from compiling your program):

```
$ objdump -S test
int main()
{
  40066d:       55                      push   %rbp
  40066e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400671:       48 81 ec 20 02 00 00    sub    $0x220,%rsp
  400678:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  40067f:       00 00 
  400681:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  400685:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    char name[20],address[500];
    printf("enter your name::: \n");
  400687:       bf a4 07 40 00          mov    $0x4007a4,%edi
  40068c:       e8 8f fe ff ff          callq  400520 <puts@plt>
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
  400691:       48 8b 15 c0 09 20 00    mov    0x2009c0(%rip),%rdx        # 601058   <__TMC_END__>
  400698:       48 8d 85 e0 fd ff ff    lea    -0x220(%rbp),%rax
  40069f:       be 14 00 00 00          mov    $0x14,%esi
  4006a4:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4006a7:       e8 b4 fe ff ff          callq  400560 <fgets@plt>
    printf("name you entered is:: %s \n", name);
  4006ac:       48 8d 85 e0 fd ff ff    lea    -0x220(%rbp),%rax
  4006b3:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  4006b6:       bf b8 07 40 00          mov    $0x4007b8,%edi
  4006bb:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006c0:       e8 7b fe ff ff          callq  400540 <printf@plt>
    printf("enter your name::: \n");
  4006c5:       bf a4 07 40 00          mov    $0x4007a4,%edi
  4006ca:       e8 51 fe ff ff          callq  400520 <puts@plt>
    fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);
  4006cf:       48 8b 15 82 09 20 00    mov    0x200982(%rip),%rdx        # 601058 <__TMC_END__>
  4006d6:       48 8d 85 00 fe ff ff    lea    -0x200(%rbp),%rax
  4006dd:       be f4 01 00 00          mov    $0x1f4,%esi
  4006e2:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4006e5:       e8 76 fe ff ff          callq  400560 <fgets@plt>
    printf("address you entered is:: %s \n", address);
  4006ea:       48 8d 85 00 fe ff ff    lea    -0x200(%rbp),%rax
  4006f1:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  4006f4:       bf d3 07 40 00          mov    $0x4007d3,%edi
  4006f9:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006fe:       e8 3d fe ff ff          callq  400540 <printf@plt>
}
```

The output from both is just explanatory. I trunctated it because it is quite extensive ...